# Using Redim to set array data type

Tags: vba, excel

When I first create an array I know it's best to set the data type, as the default `Variant` type is slow and otherwise best avoided in VBA

I notice that

```
Redim t(1 To 10) As String
```

appears to have the same effect as

```
Dim t() As String
Redim t(1 To 10)
```

but I wonder; does the first option first cast `t()` as `Variant` then convert to `String`, wasting memory with a double write?
Or is the second option actually slower because of the 2 lines. What actually happens in memory when I `Dim` an array without specifying its size?

Of course

```
Dim t(1 To 10) As String
```

comes across as the most efficient, but I need to `Redim Preserve` it later on anyway, so can't do that.

Comment: *"does the first option first cast t() as Variant then convert to String"*, I would say no it doesn't.. Why would it do that, since it is the first declaration of t() ? Is there something that made suspect that? To me both statements (1 and 2) are equivalent. No `Variant` type is intermediately involved in any of them.

Comment: @A.S.H Purely from an English Language p.o.v, the use of "Re" in `Redim` suggests to me that the variable must be initialised in some way *before* it has its type/ properties set

Comment: There is probably double initialization (not sure, only examining p-code can tell), but at most you'd have that double initialization, with the first one costing almost nothing because no memory is allocated for the array. In any case, the `Variant` data type is not involved in that process. (no downvote from my part though :D)

Comment: The "Re" in `ReDim` merely hints at the keyword's proper usage, which is to *resize dynamic arrays*. The fact that `ReDim` *can* be [ab]used as a declarative statement doesn't mean that's how it *should* be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What actually happens in memory when I `Dim` an array without specifying its size?

You get an uninitialized, *dynamically-sized array*: VBA "reserves a spot" in memory. Exactly how that works is internal plumbing that only Microsoft has the answer to - unless you can reverse-engineer P-Code (assuming you can extract the compiled P-Code in the first place).

Both `Dim` and `ReDim` *can* act as declarative statements - doesn't mean they both *should* - from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251578.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The ReDim statement acts as a declarative statement if the variable it declares doesn't exist at module level or procedure level. If another variable with the same name is created later, even in a wider scope, ReDim will refer to the later variable and won't necessarily cause a compilation error, even if Option Explicit is in effect. To avoid such conflicts, **ReDim should not be used as a declarative statement, but simply for redimensioning arrays**.

---

When you say:

> Or is the second option actually slower because of the 2 lines.

You are forgetting that `Dim` is not an executable statement (you can't break on a `Dim` statement). `ReDim` is though. So both "options" are essentially identical as far as the runtime is concerned, except the first one (with `ReDim` used as a declarative statement) is against best practices.

Therefore, if you need a dynamic array, declare a dynamic array with `Dim`:

```
Dim foo() As String
```

And then when you need to resize it, use `ReDim` to do that:

```
ReDim foo(1 To bar)
```

---

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't worry about whether `Dim` is more efficient than `ReDim`, or if it's the other way around - there's a 99.9999999997% probability that if your code has performance issues, the problem is with your algorithm, not with how VBA implemented variable and array allocations.